# It is possible to display the first character in uppercase and the others in lowercase employing CSS only

Tags: css, string

For example, strings like this, that lies inside an HTML element:

```
  - One Tree 
  - one tree 
  - One tree 
  - one Tree
```

After applying the style they should be rendered as:

```
One tree
```

P.D: Only using CSS, no javascript and no additional processing.

Comment: Inside one element or one element for each string?

Comment: Impossible, with CSS only, i would say...

Comment: You could asume that is one element for each string

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ch34qxnh/

Comment: check my answer :) paste your exact code if its diff from the one I posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes perfectly possible.

See this code for example:

```css
li, 
p{
 text-transform: lowercase; 
}
li::first-letter,
p::first-letter{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>first Li Item</li>
<li>SeCOND li Item</li>
</ul>
<p>
First PitEm is herE.
</p>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/s23xr3km/

Comment: i just get to this solution too!, is a nice workaround.. the only downside is that only works for block-level elements as the ::first-letter selector can only be used with block-level elements.

Comment: show your code, maybe we can come up with something :)

Comment: thanks Nabeel, i guess is quite more complicated to explain by this mean.. for now this answer could work!

Comment: you can add an extra block level element inside your in-line one to contain this element

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two span id  first span id should have css like this

```
#spanId1 {
text-transform : capitalize;
}
#spanId2 {
text-transform :lowercase;
}
<span id = "spanId1"> One </span> <span id = "spanId2"> Tree </span>
```